# Should I use two indexes?

Tags: mysql, database-design, index, schema, primary-key

I would like to create some tables (including users table and products table) inside MySql Database with those index for each tables:

- Private Index (uses int), for relational table purpose only
- Public Index (uses 32 chars filled with UUID), will be stored at URL and visible to users

The question is should I use public index only or keep those configuration? Please for the advice, thank you!

Comment: Specifically for using in URLs, UUIDs are a really bad idea. UUIDs are for machines, not human eyes. Consider generating something understandable at a glance, from the title, product name, SKU, and keep those URLs at a reasonable length.

Comment: Similar, but different: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54690/uniqueidentifier-vs-identity-vs-material-code-which-is-the-best-choice-for-p/54741#54741